# Finding points in a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I've started coding recently and my preferred language is python. I've come across a problem I'm having trouble with.

The problem is finding the index in a 2d array where the number is either larger than the numbers to the left and right and smaller than the numbers above and below or vice versa.

I know a 2d array can be defined as `list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` but as for working out the algorithm to sort the problem is at the present time beyond me. Could someone please offer a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by left, right, up and down? What is the reference? What would the answer for the given list in the question? Can you give one more example with higher dimensional array?

Comment: Maybe I gave a bad example, say you're given number x and a 2d array of `list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]` if x = 4 find all the points in the array where x is larger than the numbers to the left and right and smaller than the numbers above and below or vice versa. My understanding is treating the 2d array as a matrix

Comment: 'find all the points in the array' what are points? What is output in the example you gave in comment? May I ask for the original source of the question?

Comment: Find the index of x in the array where the where the number is either larger than x to the left and right and smaller than x above and below or vice versa. Points was a bad term to use

Answer (score 0):

`min(enumerate(list[0]),key=lambda x:x[1])` will find the (index,value) pair with the smallest value from list[0] ((0,1) in this example). `max(enumerate(list[0]),key=lambda x:x[1])` will find the largest.

Note (since you said you're new) this is the same as:

```
def first_index(L):
    return l[1]
min(enumerate(list[0]),key=first_index)
```

`new_list=[L[0] for L in list]` will make a list containing the 0th element from each list ([1,3,5] in this example). You'll probably want to do this for each column using `for index in range(len(list[0]):`

Note (since you're new) this is the same as:

```
new_list=list()
for L in list:
    new_list.append(L[0])
```